# XML(DTD): How can I make sure one of the children of an element is required, but not necessarily a specific one?

Tags: xml, dtd

In my DTD file I have:

```
<!ELEMENT name (firstname*, surname*, companyname*)>
```

If type='person' in the xml, then it requires the `firstname` and `surname` elements, or if type='company', it requires the `companyname` element.

How can I show this in my DTD?

I have also another similar problem:

```
<!ELEMENT telephone (home*, work*, mobile*, fax*, phone*)>
```

where if it's a person it needs at least one of `home`, `work`, `mobile`; and if it's a company it needs `phone`.

UPDATE:

I think I fixed the name problem by making it:

```
<!ELEMENT name ((firstname, surname) | companyname)>
```

and I tried similar with the telephone element:

```
<!ELEMENT telephone ((phone | (home | work | mobile)), fax*)>
```

but when validating it comes up with the error:

```
The content of element type "telephone" must match "((phone|(home|work|mobile)),fax*)". [21]
```

Where it requires at least one of `home`, `work` and `mobile`, but can have multiple/all three.
Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Found out I can fix the problem by adding an extra element tag `<personal>` or `<company>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DTDs were designed on the principle that if elements have different validation requirements, they will be given different names.  If you want elements describing companies to have one set of requirements and elements describing persons to have different requirements, call them `company` and `person`, not `name`.  DTD validation binds elements to declarations based on the element's name, not based on the value of an attribute.

So:  no, DTDs offer no mechanism for saying "If the value of the `type` attribute is `person`, then use this content model, and if the value is `company`, use that one.  Of course, you can also express the constraint the other way around, and say "if the `name` element contains a `companyname` child, then the `type` attribute must have the value `company`, and if the `name` element contains a `firstname, surname` pair, then `type` must have the value `person`."  In this formulation it becomes obvious that `type` is completely redundant, and many designers would drop it.  An application that needs to know whether it's dealing with a company or a person can look at the content to see.

It's not clear what your requirements are regarding telephone numbers.  If you want at least one phone number to be required, and if you also want phone numbers optionally to be distinguished as home, work, or mobile numbers, and you want the same parent element also to hold any fax numbers, then two obvious designs are:

```
<!ELEMENT telephone-numbers ((phone | home | mobile 
                            | work)+, fax*) >
```

and

```
<!ELEMENT telephone-numers (phone+, fax*) >
<!ELEMENT phone (#PCDATA) >
<!ATTLIST phone type (home | mobile | work) #IMPLIED >
```

Comment: Thanks, with the phone numbers the requirement is that if it is a `company`, then it must have a main `phone` number to contact, and `fax` is optional; whereas if it is a `person` they can have `home`, `mobile` and `work` numbers, but must have at least one of them, and a `fax` is again optional.

Comment: In that case, I'd make 'company' contain a 'name' and 'phone' element and make 'person' contain information for persons.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up doing.